# How can I make the latest version of skyrim work with my 3 monitors?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues, monitor

I have been looking into how I can make Skyrim support my 3 monitors in nVidia surround mode. Though I have hit a snag.

I was able to find many people talking about how there are fixes that work. Most people refer to this [link](http://www.wsgf.org/dr/elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/en).

It seems Hayden's patch is the one everyone likes.

The problem is his patch tool stopped supporting Skyrim at v1.6.89.0. They stopped patching the game at 1.9.x so I am thinking that tool will not work for me.

So my question is simple. How can I make Skyrim work on my 3 monitor setup? I have all of the DLCs for the game too, any fix has to work with the whole game.

Any suggestions?

Comment: so jealous... :(

Answer (score 1):

The following was taken from [Here](http://windows7themes.net/en-us/how-to-play-skyrim-on-multiple-3-monitors/)

This works if you have your screens set to extend

1. If you installed Skyrim via Steam, go to
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\skyrim\Skyrim – this path could be different depending on where exactly you installed Steam. If you do not have Steam, open up your Skyrim folder
2. Right-click on Skyrim.Prefs.ini and click on Open With, then select “notepad” or “notepad++”
3. Scroll down until you find [Display] then look for iSize H and iSize W
4. Replace the entries iSize with the size of your desktop. Simply multiply your current resolution e.g. with the number of your monitors e.g. 1920 x 3 = 5760

If this doesn't work i would use Haydens fix, but of course back up your game first, but there should be no reason why it wouldn't still work. I unfortunately can't test it because I no longer have 3 monitors but the first method mentioned is how i did it when i played skyrim, (i stopped playing shortly after the most recent DLC and i had a 3 monitor setup then so it really should work)

Comment: Yeah that does work. But it makes the image all distorted on the screen as it tried to stretch it over the whole thing. The menus are all screwed up too. Good idea though.

Comment: The only option is to try haydens fix which is the most upto date solution